# in the default ASP.NET project created using VS2010, where is |DataDirectory| set?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-express, app-data, datadirectory

I see the following connection string in the default web.config:

```
connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
```

I'm at the point when I want to change the connection string, but I cannot find where |DataDirectory| is set. I know it's pointing to a folder called `App_Data` under the root of my role, where the file `aspnetdb.mdf` is located.

Looking at this page: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/

it states that the SetData method is used to set the location; however I searched the entire solution and I cannot find a SetData call, or another reference to `|DataDirectory|`. It also states that as a default it uses the application folder; however I know that is not true since the file is located under the `App_Data` folder.

Any suggestions where it is set/where I should call the SetData method to set it? The first part is mroe helpful since it's a mystery to me atm :P

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can set or modify the value of the "data directory" - that's more or less a hard-coded "alias" for the `app_data` directory and cannot be changed. If you need to change the path to the MDF file, you need to provide a full, existing path

Answer (score 0):

App_data Folder is Used for Storing the Local Database, you can Check this site for information [project structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx)

To set The data, You can use AppDomain class : [appDomain class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37z40s1c.aspx)

and this example may help you to understand easily [App domain example](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html)